# integration limit

Tags: integration

How the integration, \begin{align}I=
\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}
{\rm e}^{-\left(r - {\rm i}kR/2\right)^{2}}
\,r\,{\rm d}r
\\[3mm]\end{align}
can be written as \begin{align}I=
\Im\int_{-\infty - {\rm i}kR/2}^{\infty - {\rm i}kR/2}{\rm e}^{-r^{2}}
\,\left(r + {1 \over 2}\,{\rm i}kR\right)\,{\rm d}r
\end{align}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Substitute $$r' = r - \frac{1}{2}ikR$$
and then relabel $r' \leftrightarrow r$

Comment: then where will go the exponential?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I meant how $\left(r + {1 \over 2}\,{\rm i}kR\right)$ this term escaped from the exponential?

Comment: Your exponential has $r - \frac{1}{2}ikR$ in it. When you make the substitution, this becomes just $r'$.